# Conditional probability - when is the fraction defined (representation of a strong syllogism with conditional probabilities)?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In Jaynes' [book *Probability Theory: the Logic of Science*](http://www.med.mcgill.ca/epidemiology/hanley/bios601/GaussianModel/JaynesProbabilityTheory.pdf) (page $65$ in the pdf, i.e. page $35$ in the book), the author says that the strong syllogism

> $$A\implies B$$
> $$ A$$
> $$\therefore B$$

corresponds to the product rule:

$p(B|AC) = \frac{p(AB|C)}{p(A|C)}$ where $C$ is defined as $C\equiv A\implies B$

My question is (since it hasn't been specified in the book) under which conditions do we have $p(A|C)>0$ (so that the fraction is defined)?

My guess is that, since $P(A|C) = \frac{p(AC)}{p(C)}$ and that $p(C)$ is finite, the condition for $p(A|C)$ to be non-zero is that $p(AC)$ is non-zero as well. This, in a discrete space would mean that $A\cap C \neq \emptyset$ .

Is my reasoning right ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "$p.$" If it's a density instead of a probability, there are problems requiring a measure-theoretic resolution.

Comment: Well Jaynes has gone through a very verbose derivation of what is $p$. Unfortunately I could barely follow his argument but apparently $p(x)=w^m (x)$ where $w$ is some monotonic function

Comment: @niobium Perhaps you can benefit from having a peek at Volume 1 of David Blower. You can download the PDF from [here](https://www.bayesinaction.nl/).